# Select the text and copy to clipboard when focused specific textarea in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have many textareas on my page

```
<textarea onClick="copyToClipboard(this);">mobile</textarea>
<textarea onClick="copyToClipboard(this);">computer</textarea>
<textarea onClick="copyToClipboard(this);">chair</textarea>
.
.
.
```

I want to select the text and copy to clipboard when focused that textarea in pure JavaScript without using any library.

My js code is

```
function copyToClipboard()
{
   this.select(); // I don't know how to select in JavaScript
   document.execCommand("copy");

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the selected text using `window.getSelection()` function with pure Javascript.

> I've edited the code as per your requirements. To get all the textarea content selected use [`select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) function.

```js
function copyToClipboard(elem) {
console.log(elem.value)
 elem.focus();
 elem.select();

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = window.getSelection();
document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<textarea class onClick="copyToClipboard(this)">Computer</textarea>
<textarea class onClick="copyToClipboard(this)">Mouse</textarea>
<textarea class onClick="copyToClipboard(this)">Keyboard</textarea>

<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: text selection must also be automatic.

Comment: I don't need button rather clicked textarea text should be selected and copied.

Comment: You want the text to be copied to clipboard when user clicks on the textarea, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea>mobile</textarea>
<textarea>computer</textarea>
<textarea>chair</textarea>
```